# Example to generate dynamically image from heroku ruby

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I would like to generate simple image and show it on my we page.

similar this
/number/681717

```
require 'RMagick'
require 'sinatra'
...

 get '/number/color' do
 # Create a 10x10 red image.
 f = Image.new(10,10) { self.background_color = color_from_url }
```

Anybody can help me to write this code?

Comment: Do you want help generating the image, or displaying the image once it has been generated?

Answer (score 0):

try this example. Seems pretty straight forward to me: http://ferryzhou.wordpress.com/2012/06/09/heroku-sinatra-rmagick/